# find all items that wasn't bought by a person and count the times it was bought

Tags: neo4j, cypher, gremlin

I have a graph that looks like this.

[image]

I want to find all the items bought by the people, who bought the same items as `Gremlin` using `cypher`.

Basically I want to imitate the query in the `gremlin` examples that looks like this

```
g.V().has("name","gremlin")
    .out("bought").aggregate("stash")
    .in("bought").out("bought")
        .where(not(within("stash")))
    .groupCount()
        .order(local).by(values,desc)
```

I was trying to do it like this

```
MATCH (n)-[:BOUGHT]->(g_item)<-[:BOUGHT]-(r),
      (r)-[:BOUGHT]->(n_item)
WHERE 
    n.name = 'Gremlin' 
    AND NOT (n)-[:BOUGHT]->(n_item)
RETURN n_item.id, count(*) as frequency
ORDER by frequency DESC
```

but it seems it doesn't count `frequencies` properly - they seem to be twice as big.

```
4 - 4
5 - 2
3 - 2
```

While `3` and `5` was bought only once and `4` was bought 2 times.
What's the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Cypher is interested in paths, and your MATCH finds the following:

- 2 paths to item 3 both through Rexter (via items 2 and 1)
- 2 paths to item 5 through Pipes (via items 1 and 2)
- 4 paths to item 4 via Rexter and Pipes (via items 1 and 2 for each person)

Basically the items are being counted multiple times because there are multiple paths to that same item per individual person via different common items with Gremlin.

To get accurate counts, you either need to match to distinct `r` users, and only then match out to items the `r` users bought (as long as they aren't in the collection of items bought by Gremlin), OR you need to do the entire match, but before doing the counts, get distinct items with respect to each person so each item per person only occurs once...then get the count per item (counts across all persons).

Here's a query that uses the second approach

```
MATCH (n:Person)-[:BOUGHT]->(g_item) 
WHERE n.name = 'Gremlin' 
WITH n, collect(g_item) as excluded
UNWIND excluded as g_item // now you have excluded list to use later
MATCH (g_item)<-[:BOUGHT]-(r)-[:BOUGHT]->(n_item)
WHERE r <> n AND NOT n_item in excluded
WITH DISTINCT r, n_item
WITH n_item, count(*) as frequency
RETURN n_item.id, frequency
ORDER by frequency DESC
```

You should be using labels in your graph, and you should use them in your query in order to leverage indexes and quickly find a starting point in the graph. In your case, an index on :Person(name), and usage of the :Person label in the query, should make this quick even as more nodes and more :Persons are added to the graph.

EDIT

If you're just looking for conciseness of the query, and don't have a large enough graph where performance will be an issue, then you can use your original query but add one extra line to get distinct rows of `r` and `n_item` before you count the item. This ensures that you only count an item per person once when you get the count.

Note that forgoes optimizations for handling excluded items (it will do a pattern match per item rather than aggregating the collection of bought items and doing a collection membership check), and it aggregates on items while doing property access rather than doing property access only after aggregating by the node.

```
MATCH (n:Person)-[:BOUGHT*2]-(r)-[:BOUGHT]->(n_item)
WHERE n.name = 'Gremlin' 
WITH DISTINCT n, r, n_item
WHERE NOT (n)-[:BOUGHT]->(n_item)
RETURN n_item.id, count(*) as frequency
ORDER by frequency DESC
```

I am adding a quick shortcut in your match, using :BOUGHT*2 to indicate two :BOUGHT hops to `r`, since we don't really care about the item in-between.

Comment: Hm...The query on Cypher doesn't look as intuitive as on Gremlin. Cypher wasn't designed for such queries?

Comment: It's the grouping that is different. As mentioned, Cypher is path-centric, it is looking for all possible paths to the node in question, and since the query is going through the same persons multiple times (per common item with your starting person) the counts are off. If you had no need to get distinct persons first (or distinct person/item combinations) then the original approach would be correct. This particular use case just happens to be more verbose. Also I'm erring on the side of performance with respect to handling excluded items and doing property access at the end.

Comment: `If you had no need to get distinct persons first (or distinct person/item combinations) ` hm it can be avoided? I only need items

Comment: The distinct person/items pairs are necessary so that your counts are accurate. What's being thrown off is that distinct persons are being matched to multiple times via different paths/items, so at some point (either at the person level or the person/item level) you've got to get the distinct values before aggregating. If you just needed the suggested items without counts, that's easy, just do the full match pattern and `RETURN DISTINCT n_item.id`. I'm guessing you need the counts though, 1 item count per person who matched to it.

Comment: Yeah, I need counts because I want to rank it (though probably I could apply some algorithm here)